# Why do Linux command man pages call the same thing by different names?

Tags: bash

```
column
       -s
              Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.

sort
       -t, --field-separator=SEP
              use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

cut
       -d, --delimiter=DELIM
              use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

awk
       -F fs
       --field-separator fs
              Use fs for the input field separator (the value of the FS predefined variable).
```

It's really difficult to remember all of them.

Comment: Probably because they were originally developed by different people in different places at different times (at a time Linux didn't even exist yet)

Comment: it gets easier as you go along. I mean you know the concept exists its might simply be opening a man page and finding out. I assume you know you can search a man page. Think `vi`, something like `/delim` would work in most of your above cases. Knowing that makes navigating them that much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural language also sometimes has different words for the same thing. Why would it be different in information science? While it might be desirable to have only one term/word/expression (see!) for the same thing/object (see again!), especially in science, this is wishful thinking at best. It's just a fact that different people come up with the same concepts at the same time but name it with different words. We're all individualists, after all.

So my advice is to strive for consistent naming/terminology (yet again) **in your own texts** (using existing terminology where possible) and just be aware that other vocabulary exists for any texts written by other people/folks/peers.

Comment: I like this answer. largely for the second paragraph. striving for consistency can be tough, especially if you work in a small shop. Sometimes even proper documentation of your code is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments differ since these programs were all authored by (terminally) unrelated developers for different operating systems, I guess.

Even these days, *BSD commands often behave strangely from GNU/Linux standpoint and vice versa.